# Writing a For loop that prints 1 2 ... userNum?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Here is the original prompt:

"Write a `for-loop` that prints: 1 2 .. userNum. Print a space after each number, including after the last number. Ex: `userNum = 4` prints:
`1 2 3 4`"

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountToNum {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

      int userNum = 0;
      int i = 0;

      userNum = 4;

      for (userNum = 1; userNum <= 4; ++userNum) {
         System.out.print(userNum + " ");  
      }

      System.out.println("");

      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what results you're expecting and what results you're actually receiving.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `for-loop` needs to use two different variables, one for checking against, and one for incrementing. You're also incrementing your variable before running the loop (`++userNum`), which means that you're counting from 2 to 4 instead of 1 to 4 like you meant to.

So, in your case, you would do the following:

```
for (i = 1; i <= userNum; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 1; i <= userNum; i++) {
   System.out.print(i + " ");  
}
```

What else did you declare `i` for?
You should use it when you declare it ;)

Answer (score 0):

To print a range of numbers using a for-loop from 1 to a provided ending point, use this:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= end; x++) {
    System.out.println(x + " ");
}
```

I believe that the problem with the code that you presented is that you're mixing up the ending point (where you call it `userNum`) and the temporary variable with which you iterate (which I call `x`, though different conventions may use `i`).